# Why similar antrl2 grammar does not produce non-determenism warning?

Tags: antlr2

I'm trying to create antlr grammar to parse javadoc comment. I use ANTLR v2.

Why first grammar produces non-determinism warnings and second one does not?
I thought that they are similar.

**First grammar:**

```
class TestParser extends Parser;

options {
    buildAST = true;
    k = 2;
}

startRule: START TEXT END;

class TestLexer extends Lexer;

options {
    k = 2;
}

START: "/**";
END: "*/";

TEXT: (
    {LA(2)!='/'}? '*'
    | ~('*')
    )+;
```

Warnings:

> ```
> warning:lexical nondeterminism between rules START and TEXT upon
> k==1:'/'
> k==2:'*'
> warning:lexical nondeterminism between rules END and TEXT upon
> k==1:'*'
> k==2:'/'
> ```

**Second grammar:**

```
class TestParser extends Parser;

options {
    buildAST = true;
    k = 2;
}

startRule: "/**" TEXT "*/";

class TestLexer extends Lexer;

options {
    k = 2;
}

TEXT: (
    {LA(2)!='/'}? '*'
    | ~('*')
    )+;
```